# In Google Map V3, how to put a label inside and above a polygon?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, label, polygon

In Google Map V3, how to put a label inside and above a polygon?
There's no label overlay as in V2
When I use the library maplabel, I can put the text inside, but not above, even if I specify an higher Z-index.
Thanks
Phil

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_zipcode_map_whiteBg.html) (uses FusionTablesLayer for the polygon, InfoBox for the label)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Map Label and Polygons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714031/google-maps-javascript-api-v3-map-label-and-polygons)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps get the center of coordinates (place label at center of polygon)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956691/google-maps-get-the-center-of-coordinates-place-label-at-center-of-polygon)

Answer (score 8):

maplabel renders its text on a canvas in the mapPane, which normally renders below all zIndex values in the floatPane.
To bring the mapPane canvas into your zIndex order, try:

```
var mapLabel = new MapLabel({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(yourLat, yourLng),
    text: 'test',
    zIndex: 101} );
$(mapLabel.getPanes().mapPane).css('z-index', mapLabel.zIndex);
```

Comment: This is perfect. Should be the most upvoted and accepted answer :)

Answer (score 7):

It's too late but I have faced the same problem and this code works fine!

```
var triangleCoords = [
    { lat:30.655993, lng: 76.732375 },
    { lat: 30.651379, lng: 76.735808},
    { lat: 30.653456, lng: 76.729682}
]

var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords ,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
});
attachPolygonInfoWindow(bermudaTriangle)

function attachPolygonInfoWindow(polygon) {
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'mouseover', function (e) {
        infoWindow.setContent("Polygon Name");
        var latLng = e.latLng;
        infoWindow.setPosition(latLng);
        infoWindow.open(map);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [google-maps-utility-library](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library)

Set label content, find [center position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081021/how-to-get-the-center-of-a-polygon-in-google-maps-v3) of your polygon and thats it :)

```
var labelOptions = {
    content: label,
    boxStyle: {
      textAlign: "center",
      fontSize: "8pt",
      width: "50px"
    },
    disableAutoPan: true,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-25, 0),
    position: this.my_getBounds(gpoints).getCenter(),
    closeBoxURL: "",
    isHidden: false,
    pane: "mapPane",
    enableEventPropagation: true
};

var polygonLabel = new InfoBox(labelOptions);
polygonLabel.open(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

First extend the Polygon class with your own version of the missing function, let's call it poly_getBounds()

```
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.poly_getBounds=function(){
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds()
    this.getPath().forEach(function(element,index){bounds.extend(element)})
    return bounds
}
```

Add this for customize label:

```
function Labelx(opt_options) {
    // Initialization
    this.setValues(opt_options);
    // Labelx specific
    var span = this.span_ = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.cssText = 'position: relative; left: 0%; top: -8px; ' +
              'white-space: nowrap; border: 0px; font-family:arial; font-weight:bold;' +
              'padding: 2px; background-color: #ddd; ' +
                'opacity: .75; ' +
                'filter: alpha(opacity=75); ' +
                '-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=75)"; ' +
                '-khtml-opacity: .75; ' +
                '-moz-opacity: .75;';

    var div = this.div_ = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(span);
    div.style.cssText = 'position: absolute; display: none';
};
```

And now use it:

```
var lbl = new Labelx({ map: map, position: polygon.polygon.poly_getBounds().getCenter() },true);
                    lbl.set('text', 'Label 1');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `position` field of InfoBox. Get the center position of the polygon using below code.

`const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(new window.google.maps.LatLng(lat1,lng1));
bounds.extend(new window.google.maps.LatLng(lat2,lng2));
..
..
let polygonCenter = bounds.getCenter();`