# Put label on Google Maps polygon received by GeoJson data

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to put labels with information (or a div with a label) on polygons which are drawn by the below code fragment. Style attributes were applied successfully to the features (of type Polygon). Does anybody know how add text to this features which will be shown on the centre of the polygons?

```
function handleGeoJson(data) {

    map.data.addGeoJson(data);

    map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {

        if (feature.getProperty('isColorful')) {
            color = feature.getProperty('color');
        }
        return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */( {
            fillColor : color,
            strokeColor : color,
            strokeWeight : 1,
        });
    });

    map.data.setStyle(featureStyle);

}
```

Comment: related question [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Map Label and Polygons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714031/google-maps-javascript-api-v3-map-label-and-polygons/12716168#12716168)

Comment: related question [Google Maps get the center of coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956691/google-maps-get-the-center-of-coordinates/19957258#19957258)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a way to get the center of your polygon (like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956691/google-maps-get-the-center-of-coordinates-place-label-at-center-of-polygon/19957258#19957258), or with preprocessing your data), the [Google Maps Map Label library](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label) can be used to put your text at that point on the map.